# Groovy: permutations() with size limit

Tags: algorithm, groovy

I have a problem to solve. My algorithm is assigning Players to Positions. On the start I have a list of about 16 positions and 4 players. The problem is to assing every player to it's closest positions so the overall distance is as low as possible.

I've already done this:

```
List players = ...
List positions = ...
Set posPerms = positions.permutations().collect { it.subList(0, playmakers.size()) } as Set
List assignation = posPerms.min { List perm ->
    int v = 0
    perm.eachWithIndex { Position pos, int index ->
        v += pos.distance(players[index])
    }
    v
}
[players, assignation].transpose().collectEntries { it }
```

I get what I want, but the performance is a problem. positions.permutations() generates massive lists. Is there any more optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have always at most 4 player and the number of positions is smaller than 100 (like your 16 start positions), then checking all possible position and players takes 100<sup>4</sup>, which is small enough. but if you looking for faster solution (harder implementation) You can use [Maximum Weighted Matching by Edmound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm#Weighted_matching), First you should create a graph, you can draw graph, by setting

```
Vertices = players position Union available position as nodes.
Edges = draw edge between each player and all available positions
```

For setting weight to edges you should do it in reverse, In fact first find the maximum distance (between all possible (player , position) pair, name it MaxDistance, now set your graph edges as MaxDistance - EdgeDistance + 1, here EdgeDistance is distance between player and desired position.

You can find good implementation of Edmond's algorithm in c++ in [Lemon package](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`eachPermutation`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#eachPermutation%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method to avoid building the set of permutations in memory.

That said, with 16 positions there will be about 2 billion permutations.  You might want to think about a more efficient algorithm.  I think this problem is an instance of the [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  The [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) can solve this using a matrix of values of size `players` * `positions`, instead of the factorial of `positions`.